# Google App Engine Java image service not working when uploading .ico file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The Google documentation for the Image service state that:

> Image data is represented as a byte[] of data, in any of the supported
>   formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF (including animated GIF), BMP, TIFF, and ICO
>   formats. The format can be accessed via the Image.getFormat() method.
>   The image format may be converted during transformation.

I have code that gets a list of blob keys using

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
        .getBlobstoreService();

    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(httpServletRequest);
```

Then, later on, it tries to get the imageUrl:

```
ServingUrlOptions servingOptions
            = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(b).secureUrl(false);
          String imageUrl = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService()
              .getServingUrl(servingOptions);
```

This command fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NOT_IMAGE: Failed to read image
        at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.getServingUrl(ImagesServiceImpl.java:282)
```

The code seems to work fine for jpgs and pngs. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you share an example of ICO image with us that gives you an error?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried several images on both the live site and local server with no luck. Here is one I have tried: http://codeavengers.com/favicon.ico

Comment: Are you using App Engine standard? Can you provide a full code example? (Removing any sensitive info)